# Django REST view creates new instead of updating object

Tags: django, rest

I'm using the Django REST framework for the first time. It looks, from the documentation, like `serialzer.save()` updates an object when given a primary key and creates a new one when not. However, when I go to update an object it creates a new one. (I have not tried to create a new object yet). In `serializers.py` I have this:

```
class ThingCurrentClassSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    active = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ThingCurrentClass
        fields = ['title', 'active', 'description_short', 'description_long',
              'length_in_minutes', 'adult_only', 'adult_only_reason',
              'handout_fee', 'handout_limit', 'material_fee', 'material_limit',
              'fee_itemization', 'scheduling_notes', 'special_needs_notes', 'heat_source',
              'topic', 'track', 'tags', 'private_camp']
```

In my `views.py` I have this:

```
class ThingCurrentClassList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ThingCurrentClass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThingCurrentClassSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    success_url = reverse_lazy('instructables/')
    template_name = 'thingcurrentclass_list.html'


    def get(self, request):
        queryset = ThingCurrentClass.objects.all()
        return Response({'thingcurrentclasses': queryset})

class ThingCurrentClassDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ThingCurrentClass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ThingCurrentClassSerializer
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'thingcurrentclass_detail.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('instructables/')

    def get(self, request, pk):
        thingcurrentclass = get_object_or_404(ThingCurrentClass, pk=pk)
        serializer = ThingCurrentClassSerializer(thingcurrentclass)
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'thingcurrentclass': thingcurrentclass})

    def post(self, request, pk):
        thingcurrentclass = get_object_or_404(ThingCurrentClass, pk=pk)
        serializer = ThingCurrentClassSerializer(thingcurrentclass, data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'thingcurrentclass': thingcurrentclass})
        serializer.save()
        return redirect('thingcurrentclass_list')
```

In the `thingcurrentclass_list.html` template I have this:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<html><body>
<h1>Class List</h1>
{% if thingcurrentclasses %}

    <ul>
        {% for thingcurrentclass in thingcurrentclasses %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'thingcurrentclass_detail' pk=thingcurrentclass.id %}"> {{ thingcurrentclass.title }}</a> </li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>There are no books in the library.</p>
{% endif %}
</body></html>

{% endblock %}
```

And in the `thingcurrentclass_detail.html` template I have this:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% load rest_framework %}
{% block content %}
<html><body>

<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

<form action="/instructables/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer template_pack='rest_framework/vertical' %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</body></html>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but a combination of naming the view in `urls.py` and setting the `form action` in `thingcurrentclass_detail` to "" solved this problem.